# Running javascript inside php without echo

Tags: javascript, php

So I have a php file on my server which handles HTTP POST requests. When it receives a post request, it runs a javascript script.

Currently I have the script with echo'...';
But the problem is that with the script inside echo, it simply sends the raw code to the place where the HTTP post was generated from without actually running the script.

Is there a way I can run the script without echoing it back.

Thanks

```
<?php

define('VERIFY_TOKEN', 'abc');
$method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];

if ($method == 'GET' && $_GET['hub_mode'] == 'subscribe' && $_GET['hub_verify_token'] == VERIFY_TOKEN) {
echo $_GET['hub_challenge'];
} 

else if ($method == 'POST') {

echo '
<script type="text/javascript" src="parse-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">         

        Parse.initialize("ID1", "ID2");

        var TestObject = Parse.Object.extend("Test");
        var testObject = new TestObject();
        testObject.set("key", "post");
        testObject.save();
</script>';
}
?>
```

Comment: and how you know that it does not work? BTW you're trying to achieve something magical

Comment: PHP runs on the server. JS runs on the browser.

Comment: The code will run.Php creates the html at the time of request, convert it to corresponding html and send it back.The browser receives pure html.So don't bother about that.The rest is up to the browser which can process js, since it is client side script.The js will work fine, even if its echoing.

Comment: Can you post you javascript code on the HTML page?

Comment: Executing the script can be done only from the browser.

Comment: @GeorgeGarchagudashvili : The script is supposed to update an online database. So if it works I'll know

Comment: So seems it uses ajax, than you can see anything in developer tools with `network` tab

Answer (score 1):

you can try like this

```
<?php else if ($method == 'POST') {?>
<script type="text/javascript" src="parse-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">         

        Parse.initialize("ID1", "ID2");

        var TestObject = Parse.Object.extend("Test");
        var testObject = new TestObject();
        testObject.set("key", "post");
        testObject.save();
</script>
<?php }
?>
```

else i don't think there is any other way

Comment: This does exactly same thing as with `echo`.

Answer (score 1):

When your browser receives the response, it's expecting proper HTML (and two `<script>` tags are not proper HTML). Try wrapping your response in some minimal HTML:

```
echo '
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="parse-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">         

            Parse.initialize("ID1", "ID2");

            var TestObject = Parse.Object.extend("Test");
            var testObject = new TestObject();
            testObject.set("key", "post");
            testObject.save();
    </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that I can't really do that since javascript needs browser. And since there is only php file I can't make it work with js so I switched to all php.